# closing postgres connection of intellij

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, makefile

I am working on a postgres DB on from within intellij. I trigger a script (a makefile) that resets the database and other things. To execute the script, the open DB connection from intellij must be closed. I can do that manually by clicking on close connection but i want to automate it.

is there a way to close the DB connection of intellij to the data from the outside?

Comment: >To execute the script, the open DB connection from intellij must be closed.

Do you execute script from IDE? Could you clarify, why do you need to terminate existing connection?

You can assign a shortcut to Database tool window and use the shortcut to navigate to it, then terminate connection via Ctrl/CMD+F2 shortcut. You can assign a Marto to these actions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Comment: i am running the script from the console from intellij. it trys to drop the database but cannot and produces an error: 
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database  is being accessed by other users

Comment: The only way I see is to kill the process externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a shell script to be executed by the makefile.

it connects to the database and disconnects active sessions (except mine):

```
psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=name -c "SELECT
pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM 
pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = current_database() AND 
pid <> pg_backend_pid();"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to close the connection not from IDE is to find in your OS process tree corresponding java process created by IDE for the connection and kill it.

To close it quickly from IDE you can assign a shortcut to Database tool window and use this shortcut to navigate to it, then terminate connection via Ctrl/CMD+F2 shortcut. You can assign a [Macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) to these actions.